# Compiling assembly (.s file) using gcc error c++ standard library

Tags: assembly, g++, llvm, 64-bit

I am trying to compile an `.s` file I produced using llvm (llc) back to an `.exe` file.

When trying to compile the `.s` file using g++ with `g++ output.s -o test.exe`, I get multiple errors of

> output.s:344: Error: invalid character '?' in operand 1

The error happens at calls like

> callq "?widen@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEBADD@Z

So it has some issues on these c++ standard library calls.
How can I make gcc/g++ recognize these?

Comment: What input did you give `llc` to get this `.s`?  Is the `?` the symbol name a literal ASCII / UTF-8 `?` (0x3f byte), or is that your terminal translating it to something else?  This doesn't seem like a [mcve].  Does `clang` assemble this `.s` which `g++` doesn't like?  Oh, also I assume you're on Windows since you mention a `.exe`?  So I suppose the assembler your `g++` is running is some version of GNU Binutils `as`.

Comment: I gave llc the .ll file that was produced by llvm. I used "retdec" to lift a windows PE .exe to llvm IR, about the ?, i dont know, it just seems like name mangling "syntax". I work inside linux, so g++ is running on ubuntu

Comment: A hexdump will tell you what bytes make up the `?`.  e.g. `hexdump -C output.s  | less`

Comment: Use `clang` to compile this assembly.